# Shouldn't the *later* question be marked "duplicate"?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

This question was marked duplicate about an hour ago:

[execute a bash command on a list of files on stdin and redirect the stdout to related files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10110259/execute-a-bash-command-on-a-list-of-files-on-stdin-and-redirect-the-stdout-to-re/)

Observe that this question is from 2012, and the one it supposedly duplicated is 2013.

Comment: Your wish is granted!

Answer (score 5):

*Shouldn't the **later** question be marked "duplicate"?*

### Not necessarily.

Not if the later question is better and / or has better answers.
Duplicate links should link to the best possible question / answer available.

Basically, quality over age.